# Build service could not start build operation: internal error: failed to send the system info to the build service

Tags: build, swift4, ios9, xcode10

I just installed XCode10 and I am trying to run my code on ios8 simulator, in the process I am facing below error

```
"Build service could not start build operation: internal error: failed to send the system info to the build service"
```

Comment: That just seems to be a random Xcode 10 thing. I ran an app yesterday, restarted my computer, got this error, cleaned the build and restarted Xcode, and it's fine now, but there seems no rhyme or reason, and I'm not even sure how to file a bug report for something that isn't a problem anymore.

Comment: Having this with Xcode 13.4.1 - very annoying

Answer (score 18):

I think your Xcode is just in the process of indexing the files. It may take some time to finish but when it's done, just give it a try.

If it's not helpful, try reopening your xcode - it works for me after the indexing process finished.

Comment: I've recently had XCode10 glitch several times with different bugs (from saying I have 30 syntax errors that did not exist and thereafter compiling to crashing multiple times) and this appears to be another bug... I got the same error as Arti above, and for me, it did not work after restarting XCode, restarting my computer, and waiting for the indexing to finish. Will add again once this fixes / if anything changes

Answer (score 11):

No needs to restart system. Just restart Xcode -> clean build fix this issue for me.

Comment: Yes - with Xcode 13.3, simply restarting Xcode resolved this issue.

Comment: Xcode 14.3, this worked for me

Answer (score 7):

Restarting my Mac was the only solution for me. Restarting Xcode did not fix. We are back to Microsoft days.

Answer (score 3):

Very very strange, you may laugh while reading my answer but **restarting my laptop** did the trick for me, I was trying to make ios build in my ionic1 app

Comment: yep! restart the mac, did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In my case opening 2 projects at a time using Xcode got the hitch. So I closed all and opened one then it was working fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30658292)

Answer (score 0):

I commented above but thereafter figured out another possible solution to try. Cleaning the project worked. (I restarted XCode10, my computer, and waited for indexing to finish - neither of these worked for me, at least.)

```
Command + Shift + K
```

or equivalently

```
Product > Clean Build Folder
```

Answer (score 0):

I quit my Xcode and delete some file related to Xcode and empty the bin. Then I open a Xcode project. Its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think deleting Derived Data, doing a clean, close/reopen Xcode helped, but when I reopened Xcode I had files in "Recovered Resources" folder that appear in the Project Navigator. Doing all that other stuff AND deleting "Recovered Resources" is what worked for me. Along the way, I deleted and added back the problem files, added them to Target Membership in the File Inspector, rebuilt the Package Cache (right click on Package Dependencies), and waved a dead chicken over the keyboard.
I think deleting "Recovered Resources" was the key.

Answer (score -1):

Go to File --> Workspace Setting --> Change "Build System" to "Legacy Build System" from "New Build System

[image: Legacy Build System]

Answer (score -1):

Clean build folder should work in Xcode 15.1